# make player cutout image with kinect smoother,special anti aliasing

Tags: c#, image-processing, xna, kinect

I tried to cutout player image with using depth image of kinect but there are some problem with that , first when im using depthStreamWithPlayerIndex ,just 320x240 reslution
can used for depth stream , second problem is the function that retrive correct color pixel from depth pixel is works up to 640x480 , cause of these two problem cutouted image is not good if you want show on a high reslution, now i want to know is anyway to fix these two problem Or an algoritm to smooth output image? something like anti-aliasing ?

[image: look at player image edge]

Comment: Do you have the player and the background as a separate image?

Comment: yeah, i cut player image with common method(using playerindex in depth screen) and put on a separate background

Comment: Any word on how to do this in real time?  I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 4):

Couple of things I can think of.

If you want to even out the edges of the person, then you could do this:

- Make a [mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_mask#Image_masks) that is 255 where the player is, 0 everywhere else
- Smooth the mask (using [Gaussian blurring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) with an empirically determined parameter)
- Use this mask when composing the original player image with the new background

You could replace the smoothing step with morphological operations (e.g. [dilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_%28morphology%29), open/close).

Once you've put the player on the new background, you could ["feather"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feathering) the player edges to make them stand out a bit less:

- Apply [Canny operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) to the edge mask from above
- Dilate the mask.  You now have a mask that covers the outside of the player
- Blur the parts of the composed image that are under the mask

Comment: ty  , i have not too much experience in image processing , can you give me an algorithm or a dll for these, or at least say these in simple words ;)

Comment: I don't use C# nor Windows, so I can't give you a DLL.  If you add the three images you're using (original image, player mask, new background), I can show you how to achieve your result using a different library (I use opencv).  As far as wording goes, I can't really put it any simpler, so I've added some links to my answer to make it easier for you to understand it.  As far as the algorithm goes, it's essentially what I wrote in point form.  You just need to understand each individual step, and you'll be good to go.